# Selenium IDE always returns "true" on XPath evaluation

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am working on a test in the Selenium IDE, which (among other things) looks at login.microsoftonline.com to check if a particular username is listed in the accounts that have authenticated before (from a particular browser, on a particular PC).

I am trying to evaluate for the desired username with:

```
return document.evaluate("//*[@data-test-id='correctusername@domain.com']", document) !== null
```

But it doesn't matter what I put in as the string, the variable is always set to "true".

[image: selenium test]

I tried changing the "execute" script target to both

```
return document.evaluate("//*[@data-test-id='asasdfasddf@domain.com']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
```

and

```
return document.evaluate("//*[@data-test-id='asasdfasddf@domain.com']", document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null)
```

But line 5 prints "echo: The value of usernamePresent: [object Object]" in both instances.

Using:

```
return document.evaluate("//*[@data-test-id='asasdfasddf@domain.com']", document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null) !==null
```

Results in "The value of usernamePresent: true" again.

Finally:

```
return document.evaluate("//*[@data-test-id='asasdfasddf@domain.com']", document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).numberValue
```

Returned, "echo: The value of usernamePresent: null"

The element I am looking at is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="tilesHolder" class="form-group" role="list" aria-labelledby="tileError loginHeader"
        data-bind="attr: { 'data-test-asynctilesloaded': !isTileRequestPending() }" data-test-asynctilesloaded="true">
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: sessions, as: 'session' } -->
        <div class="tile-container" data-bind="component: { name: 'tile-field',
                params: {
                    serverData: svr,
                    session: session,
                    hasFocus: $index() === 0,
                    ariaDescribedBy: $index() === 0 ? 'tileError loginHeader' : null,
                    isLogoutRequest: $parent.isLogoutRequest,
                    tileIndex: $index() },
                event: {
                    tileClick: $parent.tile_onClick,
                    forgetComplete: $parent.tile_onForgetComplete } },
                css: { 'binaryChoice list': svr.fSupportWindowsStyles }"><!--  -->

            <div class="row tile" role="listitem">
                <div class="table" tabindex="0" role="button" data-bind="
        attr: {
            'data-test-id': session.unsafe_name,
            'data-test-idp': session.idp,
            'data-test-hometenant': session.homeTenantName || '' },
        css: { 'list-item': svr.fSupportWindowsStyles },
        ariaLabel: unsafe_helpText,
        ariaDescribedBy: ariaDescribedBy,
        click: tile_onClick,
        pressEnter: tile_onClick,
        hasFocus: hasFocus" data-test-id="wronguser@domain.com" data-test-idp="0" data-test-hometenant=""
                    aria-label="Sign in with wronguser@domain.com work or school account."
                    aria-describedby="tileError loginHeader">
                    <div class="table-row">
                        <div class="table-cell tile-img">
                            <!-- ko if: session.idp === 0 -->
                            <img class="tile-img" role="presentation"
                                pngsrc="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_aad_725681b49f77650b9c9b970eb784476c.png"
                                svgsrc="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_aad_f83ebff69a4a1685e4dc9650cdab8886.svg"
                                data-bind="imgSrc"
                                src="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_aad_f83ebff69a4a1685e4dc9650cdab8886.svg">
                            <!-- /ko -->

                            <!-- ko if: session.idp === 1 --><!-- /ko -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="table-cell text-left content"
                            data-bind="css: { 'content': !svr.fSupportWindowsStyles }">
                            <div
                                data-bind="text: ((session.isSignedIn || session.isSamsungSso) &amp;&amp; session.unsafe_fullName) || session.unsafe_displayName">
                                wronguser@domain.com</div>

                            <!-- ko if: (session.isSignedIn || session.isSamsungSso) && session.fullName --><!-- /ko -->

                            <!-- ko if: session.isSignedIn && !session.isWindowsSso && !session.isSamsungSso && !iFrameSrc() --><!-- /ko -->

                            <!-- ko if: session.iFrameSrc --><!-- /ko -->

                            <!-- ko if: session.isWindowsSso --><!-- /ko -->

                            <!-- ko if: session.isSamsungSso --><!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- ko ifnot: hideTileMenu -->
                <div class="table-cell tile-menu tile-menu-float">
                    <div tabindex="0" role="button" data-bind="
                click: menu_onClick,
                pressEnter: menu_onClick,
                hasFocus: menuFocused,
                ariaLabel: str['TILE_STR_MenuAltText'],
                attr: {
                    'data-test-id': session.unsafe_name + '-menu-dots',
                    'data-test-idp': session.idp,
                    'aria-controls': 'tileMenu' + tileIndex,
                    'aria-expanded': menuOpen().toString() }" aria-label="Open menu"
                        data-test-id="wronguser@domain.com-menu-dots" data-test-idp="0" aria-controls="tileMenu0"
                        aria-expanded="false">

                        <!-- ko component: 'accessible-image-control' --><!-- ko if: (isHighContrastBlackTheme || hasDarkBackground || svr.fHasBackgroundColor) && !isHighContrastWhiteTheme --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (isHighContrastWhiteTheme || (!hasDarkBackground && !svr.fHasBackgroundColor)) && !isHighContrastBlackTheme -->
                        <!-- ko template: { nodes: [darkImageNode], data: $parent } --><img role="presentation"
                            pngsrc="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_more_ced331c132b5f798f1f3ab36712d4608.png"
                            svgsrc="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_more_7568a43cf440757c55d2e7f51557ae1f.svg"
                            data-bind="imgSrc"
                            src="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_more_7568a43cf440757c55d2e7f51557ae1f.svg"><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>

            <ul class="menu" role="menu" data-bind="
    visible: menuOpen,
    if: menuOpen,
    attr: { 'id': 'tileMenu' + tileIndex }" id="tileMenu0" style="display: none;"></ul>

            <!-- ko if: iFrameSrc --><!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if: forgetIFrameSrc --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: isTileRequestPending --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: unsafe_signupTileText --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko ifnot: isLogoutRequest || svr.fShowSignupTile -->
        <div class="row tile" role="listitem">
            <div id="otherTile" class="table" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-labelledby="otherTileText" data-bind="
                    css: { 'list-item': svr.fSupportWindowsStyles },
                    click: otherTile_onClick,
                    pressEnter: otherTile_onClick">
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell tile-img">
                        <img class="tile-img" role="presentation"
                            pngsrc="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_add_c9929da7ed2c1ed4745e4035cf5441cd.png"
                            svgsrc="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_add_56e73414003cdb676008ff7857343074.svg"
                            data-bind="imgSrc"
                            src="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/images/picker_account_add_56e73414003cdb676008ff7857343074.svg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="table-cell text-left content"
                        data-bind="css: { 'content': !svr.fSupportWindowsStyles }">
                        <div id="otherTileText" data-bind="text: otherTileText">Use another account</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

We can see "data-test-id="wronguser@domain.com"" in a , which is a user who has logged-in, but not the one I care about.

How do I test for the correct username, while allowing for an if/else statement to be run on the results?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

Command: Execute script

Target: **return document.querySelector("*put-selector*").textContent.includes("*searched-content*")**

Value: bool

Command: verify

Target: bool

Value: true

Note: this will search in the first selector you will put, so i recommend you to put the css selector of the main container that could have the information

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is in the comparing to NULL.

> Document.evaluate() returns an integer that corresponds to the type of
> result XPathResult to return. The following values are possible:
>
> ANY_TYPE (0) Whatever type naturally results from the given
> expression.
>
> NUMBER_TYPE (1) A result set containing a single number. Useful, for
> example, in an xpath expression using the count() function.
>
> STRING_TYPE (2) A result set containing a single string.
>
> BOOLEAN_TYPE (3) A result set containing a single boolean value.
> Useful, for example, an xpath expression using the not() function.
>
> UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE (4) A result set containing all the nodes
> matching the expression. The nodes in the result set are not
> necessarily in the same order they appear in the document.

More info is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: When I removed that "!==null", the second echo had ${usernamePresent}, "undefined".

Comment: Well, in general I do not get a bit what does your test do, because I see on your screenshot, first echo also does not work right, am I right? It says "The value of userName present = false". What should be written here? A username or a boolean, because the word 'value' confuses about the expected value here. Saying 'the issue is with comparing to NULL' I mean, the statement document.evaluate() always returns not null value in your case, it returns an integer, according to the spec, so therefore you get 'true'.

Comment: Also I think, in case you parse by document.evaluate(), you get  XPathResult, so I think, if you want to use it, you may use XPathResult.[CONSTANT from the specification], e.g: "resultType is an integer that corresponds to the type of result XPathResult to return. Use named constant properties, such as XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, of the XPathResult constructor, which correspond to integers from 0 to 9.", see here more info: https://reference.codeproject.com/dom/document/evaluate

Comment: "usernamePresent" is a variable. On line 2, I assing "false" to the variable. Then I echo the string "The value of usernamePresent" and the value stored in the variable. Since the output string is, "The value of usernamePresent: false", we can see that the variable does not contain "true".

Next, I execute the script and assign the result to the "usernamePresent" variable. When I write out the stored value of "usernamePresent" again on line 5, the value has changed from "false" to "true". I tried more ways to run document.evaluate() and added both to the original post.

Comment: I see. Okay, I also see you use hardcoded user emails in locators. Maybe then for your case it would be easier to use not "document.evaluate()" but smth that checks if the element is present? E.g. "verify element present" - this command is used to check if an element is present on the web page. If this command fails, then the execution will not stop and continue with the next commands. It will return TRUE if the specified element is present on the page; otherwise, it returns FALSE?